# How to manage object list returned from JSON file?

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I have got items from a `JSON` file and send them to my `$scope`:

```
//JS controller

.controller('MyController', function($scope, $log) {
    $http.get('JSON_FILE_URL').success(function(response){
        $scope.responseData = response;
        $scope.items = rundom(response);
    });

    $scope.refresh = function(data) {
        $log.log('refresh data :'+data);
        $scope.items = rundom(data);    
    };
}

// view.html

<ion-view view-title="myTitle" ng-controller="MyController">
    <button ng-click="refresh({{responseData}})">refresh</button>
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" ng-cloak class="fullPage">
        <div class="item item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="item in items">
            <h1>{{ item['title'] }}</h1>
        </div>
        //some code here
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I have inspect element on html, the items are there inside my function.

```
<button ng-click="refresh({"id": 0, "title": "title 0"},{"id": 1, "title": "title 1"})">refresh</button>
```

when I click on the button to refresh, nothings happens, but
I got undefined on logs: `refresh data :undefined`

Is it a type question which I didn't take into consideration?

Comment: did you try ng-click="refresh(responseData)" ?

Comment: @Oliver: You are right :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use angle brackets in the ng-click.

```
ng-click="refresh()"
```

It can access $scope anyway inside the function so there's no need to pass it

Answer (score 0):

The Olivier's answer is correct: `ng-click="refresh(responseData)"`